# How to append YTArray in a for loop as YTArray object has no attribute append?

Tags: python, yt

```py
yt_arr = YTArray([])
for i in range(10):
   yt_arr.append(i)
```

This particular type of code returns an error saying that `YTArray` has no attribute `append`. So how do I append values in the array?

Answer (score 1):

You can append the contents to a `list` and later convert it to a `YTArray` object.

```py
arr = []
yt_arr = YTArray([])
for i in range(10):
    arr.append(i) 
yt_arr = YTArray(arr,'cm') # add your symbolic reference here
```